# How to run multiple "tasks" at the same time?

Tags: c#

My code is basically something like this:

```
for each (DirectoryInfo di in directoryList)
{
    for each (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
    {
        MyTask(fi.FullName);
        Console.WriteLine(fi.FullName + " is done.");
    }
}


void MyTask(string arg0)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; 
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "converter.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-converterarguments";
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

How do I get my program to run multiple "instances" of MyTask/converter.exe at the same time?

Comment: Why not use Tasks? Also, the trick would be to have your `MyTask` return the Process, so you could call it several times and then wait for all of them.

Comment: Pay attention to the code you've written. You should create an array of them, and don't call `p.WaitForExit()` until you've `Start()`ed all of them.

Comment: Do you really want separate *processes*? Are you sure is not separate *threads* within your single program that you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You could have your MyTask return a Process that you can wait for:

```
Process MyTask(string arg0)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; 
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "converter.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-converterarguments";
    p.Start();
    return p;
}
```

and then:

```
List<Process> processes = new List<Process>();

for each (DirectoryInfo di in directoryList)
{
    for each (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles())
    {
        processes.Add(MyTask(fi.FullName));
    }
}

foreach(Process p in processes)
{
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

**Update**

You could give progress by doing something like:

```
var completed = 0;

foreach(Process p in processes)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for processes to complete. Progress: {0}/{1}"
        completed, processes.Count);

    p.WaitForExit();
    completed++;        
}

Console.WriteLine("Done. All {0} processes are complete." processes.Count);
```

The only problem with this would be if the first process takes the longest to finish, you'll have a progress of 0 for most of the time, then it will quickly complete. You might look into using Tasks instead, where you can `WaitAny` on a list of tasks. This will give you better progress, as it will update each time a new task completes.

Comment: Would it be possible to get the progress? Like how many processes have finished?

Comment: Updated with some more info on progress and that you should consider using Tasks instead.